# How to change a UILabel View to an UIImageView Xcode, Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have made a sample where there is a ScrollView and Images that Scroll in the ScrollView. When You Click on One on the Images it tells you what button image is pressed below the UIScrollView in form of a UILabelView. What I want to figure out is How do I change the Label to a UIImageView. So instead of it saying button %d when pushed. I want to show a image that i stipulate.

**Kitchens.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SlideMenuView.h"


@interface Kitchens : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIScrollView *windows;
SlideMenuView *slideMenuView;
UILabel *screenLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *windows;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SlideMenuView *slideMenuView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *screenLabel;

@end
```

**Kitchens.m**

```
#import "Kitchens.h"
#import "SlideMenuView.h"

@interface Kitchens ()

@end

@implementation Kitchens

@synthesize windows, slideMenuView, screenLabel;
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark <Touches Began/Moved/Ended/Cancelled Methods>


- (void)viewDidLoad {


// Create and position a label
screenLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 200.0f, [windows bounds].size.width-20.0f, 20.0f)];
[windows addSubview:screenLabel];

// Create buttons for the sliding menu. For simplicity I create 5 standard buttons.
NSMutableArray* buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
// Rounded rect is nice
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

// Give the buttons a width of 100 and a height of 30. The slide menu will take care of positioning the buttons.
// If you don't know that 100 will be enough, use my function to calculate the length of a string. You find it on my blog.

[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
[btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", i+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonArray addObject:btn];

// Rounded rect is nice
UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

// Give the buttons a width of 100 and a height of 30. The slide menu will take care of positioning the buttons.
// If you don't know that 100 will be enough, use my function to calculate the length of a string. You find it on my blog.

[btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
[btn1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pia05733-640-480.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonArray addObject:btn1];

UIButton *btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
// Give the buttons a width of 100 and a height of 30. The slide menu will take care of positioning the buttons.
// If you don't know that 100 will be enough, use my function to calculate the length of a string. You find it on my blog.
[btn2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
[btn2 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button3"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pia05733-640-480.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonArray addObject:btn2];

}

// initialize the slide menu by passing a suitable frame, background color and an array of buttons.
slideMenuView = [[SlideMenuView alloc] initWithFrameColorAndButtons:CGRectMake(10.0f, 30.0f, [windows bounds].size.width-20.0f,  100.0f) backgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]  buttons:buttonArray];

// Add the slide menu to the window.
[windows addSubview:slideMenuView];


[super viewDidLoad];


}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
screenLabel.text = ((UIButton*)sender).currentTitle;
UIButton *btn2 = (UIButton*)sender;
UIImage *image = btn2.currentImage;

// Set the image in the image view
self.imageView.image = image;

}

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
} else {
    return YES;
}
}

@end
```

**SlideMenuView,h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SlideMenuView : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
UIScrollView *menuScrollView;
UIImageView *rightMenuImage;
UIImageView *leftMenuImage;
NSMutableArray *menuButtons;
}
-(id) initWithFrameColorAndButtons:(CGRect)frame backgroundColor:(UIColor*)bgColor  buttons:(NSMutableArray*)buttonArray;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView* menuScrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView* rightMenuImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView* leftMenuImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* menuButtons;

@end
```

**SlideMenuView.m**

```
#import "SlideMenuView.h"


@implementation SlideMenuView
@synthesize menuScrollView, rightMenuImage, leftMenuImage;
@synthesize menuButtons;

-(id) initWithFrameColorAndButtons:(CGRect)frame backgroundColor:(UIColor*)bgColor  buttons:(NSMutableArray*)buttonArray  {

if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

    // Initialize the scroll view with the same size as this view.
    menuScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];

    // Set behaviour for the scrollview
    menuScrollView.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    menuScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = FALSE;
    menuScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = FALSE;
    menuScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    menuScrollView.bounces = FALSE;

    // Add ourselves as delegate receiver so we can detect when the user is scrolling.
    menuScrollView.delegate = self;

    // Add the buttons to the scrollview
    menuButtons = buttonArray;

    float totalButtonWidth = 0.0f;

    for(int i = 0; i < [menuButtons count]; i++)
    {
        UIButton *btn = [menuButtons objectAtIndex:i];

        // Move the buttons position in the x-demension (horizontal).
        CGRect btnRect = btn.frame;
        btnRect.origin.x = totalButtonWidth;
        [btn setFrame:btnRect];

        // Add the button to the scrollview
        [menuScrollView addSubview:btn];

        // Add the width of the button to the total width.
        totalButtonWidth += btn.frame.size.width;
    }

    // Update the scrollview content rect, which is the combined width of the buttons
    [menuScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(totalButtonWidth, self.frame.size.height)];

    [self addSubview:menuScrollView];

}
return self;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
// if the offset is less than 3, the content is scrolled to the far left. This would be the time to show/hide
// an arrow that indicates that you can scroll to the right. The 3 is to give it some "padding".
if(scrollView.contentOffset.x <= 3)
{
    NSLog(@"Scroll is as far left as possible");
}
// The offset is always calculated from the bottom left corner, which means when the scroll is as far
// right as possible it will not give an offset that is equal to the entire width of the content. Example:
// The content has a width of 500, the scroll view has the width of 200. Then the content offset for far right
// would be 300 (500-200). Then I remove 3 to give it some "padding"
else if(scrollView.contentOffset.x >= (scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width)-3)
{
    NSLog(@"Scroll is as far right as possible");
}
else
{
    // The scoll is somewhere in between left and right. This is the place to indicate that the 
    // use can scroll both left and right
}

}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Drawing code
}


- (void)dealloc {
//[menuButtons release];
//[rightMenuImage release];
//[leftMenuImage release];
//[menuScrollView release];
// [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In button Action method, get the current background image for that button and set it in an image view

```
 - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
         UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
         UIImage *image = button.currentBackgroundImage;

          // Set the image in the image view


         self.imageView.image = image;

    }
```

Comment: I did the following, IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
(Cant put 2 at signs in comment) property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView; in Kitchens.h then I put synthesize imageView in Kitchens.m  , Then I linked the tableview to imageView in the Storyboard. I Got an Error where  self.imageView.image = image; "Property imageView not found of objects of Type Kitchens" I Must be doing something wrong, Or I am not doing something. Any Advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.